# array_unique ignores 0

Tags: php, floating-point, zero, array-unique

I have an array of floats.

When I use array_unique, if I have a 0 value, it's left out of the result.

Is this correct, or is there a way around this?  What's the proper syntax to make it include 0s.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show some code or example of the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array_unique function typecasts the elements of an array as strings by default before comparison.

You might want to try:

```
array_unique($array, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

or

```
array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: SORT_NUMERIC did it.  Must be my PHP version or server or something...   Thank-you very much for your help!